# Upload Button in the Form in Tridion

Tags: content-manager

We have web-based application using asp.net and tridion.  In Tridion I have a have an existing form, with dropdown and textareas.  I want to add Upload button in trdion form component itself. Is it Possible to do so , or better should i add the upload button in asp.net User Control.  Please suggest me ASAP, as i'm new to the tridion.

Comment: What you mean by form in tridion, Tridion Web forms?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a bit more detail? When you are referring to Tridion, are you talking about the Content Manager interface, or the Content Delivery APIs you used in your web application?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going this part of your question:

> "I want to add Upload button in trdion form component itself"

From this i'm assuming you'd like to add extra functionality to the SDL Tridion GUI.

There's a lot of content out there to help you create GUI extensions, I'd recommend reading these posts, in order:

1. https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx - if you'd like to add a dialog to your cms page, it's possible to have your .net page as part of your extension.
2. http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/ - how to add functionality to the GUI without adding new menus, ribbons etc

Google is your friend, there's a bunch of great GUI extension posts out there :)